# How to simplify this OpenGL .obj model loader example?

Tags: c++, opengl, assimp

I'm trying to simplify the code from learnopengl.com/Model-Loading/Model . What I want is for the code to display the model, that's it. No camera movement, no user keyboard/mouse input. Just display the .obj model and its textures.

How can I modify this code so I get a static-like image like this:
[image]

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <learnopengl/shader_m.h>
#include <learnopengl/camera.h>
#include <learnopengl/model.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>


#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// camera
Camera camera(glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f));
float lastX = SCR_WIDTH / 2.0f;
float lastY = SCR_HEIGHT / 2.0f;
bool firstMouse = true;

// timing
float deltaTime = 0.0f;
float lastFrame = 0.0f;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);
    glfwSetCursorPosCallback(window, mouse_callback);
    glfwSetScrollCallback(window, scroll_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis (before loading model).
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // build and compile shaders
    // -------------------------
    Shader ourShader("1.model_loading.vs", "1.model_loading.fs");

    // load models
    // -----------
    Model ourModel("backpack/backpack.obj");


    // draw in wireframe
    //glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

    // render loop
    // -----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // per-frame time logic
        // --------------------
        float currentFrame = glfwGetTime();
        deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
        lastFrame = currentFrame;

        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // don't forget to enable shader before setting uniforms
        ourShader.use();

        // view/projection transformations
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        ourShader.setMat4("view", view);

        // render the loaded model
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
        model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // translate it down so it's at the center of the scene
        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)); // it's a bit too big for our scene, so scale it down
        ourShader.setMat4("model", model);
        ourModel.Draw(ourShader);


        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}



// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_W) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(FORWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_S) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(BACKWARD, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_A) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(LEFT, deltaTime);
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_D) == GLFW_PRESS)
        camera.ProcessKeyboard(RIGHT, deltaTime);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse moves, this callback is called
// -------------------------------------------------------
void mouse_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{
    if (firstMouse)
    {
        lastX = xpos;
        lastY = ypos;
        firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = xpos - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - ypos; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = xpos;
    lastY = ypos;

    camera.ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);
}

// glfw: whenever the mouse scroll wheel scrolls, this callback is called
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
void scroll_callback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{
    camera.ProcessMouseScroll(yoffset);
}
```

Here's one of the attempts I tried. I tried removing this code from the while loop:

```
        // view/projection transformations
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(camera.Zoom), (float)SCR_WIDTH / (float)SCR_HEIGHT, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        ourShader.setMat4("view", view);
```

but the program runs with no .obj model showing.

Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: Change one line: `glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();` -> `glm::mat4 view(1.0f);`

Comment: @Rabbid76 thanks! This is definitely in the right direction. What I get now is a model that is completely taking up the entire view of the frame. I tried glm::scale() to scale it down, but it still takes up the whole frame. I used glm::translate to move it back -10 on the z-axis and I like what I see, but this is just a workaround because I still want xyz to be 0,0,0. I think I need to do something with glm::perspective?

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Here's what I did:

1. Changed glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix(); -> glm::mat4 view(1.0f);
2. For projection, I used glm::ortho() instead of glm::perspective()
3. To see to model as shown in the picture, I used = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f));

Here's the full code:

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/matrix_transform.hpp>
#include <glm/gtc/type_ptr.hpp>

#include <learnopengl/shader_m.h>
#include <learnopengl/model.h>

#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <stb_image.h>


#include <iostream>

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    // ------------------------------
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

#ifdef __APPLE__
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
#endif

    // glfw window creation
    // --------------------
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

    // tell GLFW to capture our mouse
    glfwSetInputMode(window, GLFW_CURSOR, GLFW_CURSOR_DISABLED);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    // ---------------------------------------
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // tell stb_image.h to flip loaded texture's on the y-axis (before loading model).
    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

    // configure global opengl state
    // -----------------------------
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    // build and compile shaders
    // -------------------------
    Shader ourShader("1.model_loading.vs", "1.model_loading.fs");

    // load models
    // -----------
    Model ourModel("backpack/backpack.obj");

    //render loop
    //-----------
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        // input
        // -----
        processInput(window);

        // render
        // ------
        glClearColor(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // don't forget to enable shader before setting uniforms
        ourShader.use();

        // view/projection transformations
        float widthToHeighRatio = SCR_WIDTH / float(SCR_HEIGHT);
        glm::mat4 projection = glm::ortho(-widthToHeighRatio, widthToHeighRatio, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        
        // glm::mat4 view = camera.GetViewMatrix();
        glm::mat4 view(1.0f);
        ourShader.setMat4("projection", projection);
        ourShader.setMat4("view", view);

        // render the loaded model
        glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);

        model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f)); // it's a bit too big for our scene, so scale it down
        ourShader.setMat4("model", model);
        ourModel.Draw(ourShader);

        // glfw: swap buffers and poll IO events (keys pressed/released, mouse moved etc.)
        // -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
    // ------------------------------------------------------------------
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}

// process all input: query GLFW whether relevant keys are pressed/released this frame and react accordingly
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window)
{
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
}

// glfw: whenever the window size changed (by OS or user resize) this callback function executes
// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height)
{
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit misleading. Unless you really were able to get rid of *all* the other code in your question, even the #includes.

Comment: @TylerH Yes you're right. Good catch. I updated my answer with the full code.

Comment: Good update-- it could be improved further by explaining how your code here is different from the code in the question (e.g. what changes you made). That way future readers with similar code setups can learn rather than guess at what changes were made and why.